Graphical Switchuser with Netnamespaces in Wayland
I'm using 2 user accounts in different Netnamespaces like described in:
https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/use-net-namespace-vpn
The graphical output works on Xorg but refuses to provide a display on Wayland.
Creation of the Netnamespace:
ip netns add wifins
ip netns exec wifins ip addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
ip netns exec wifins ip link set lo up
ip netns exec wifins systemctl start wpa_supplicant
ip netns exec wifins dhcpcd -C resolv.conf wlp0s20f3

With that configuration I have 2 Netnamespaces:

enp0s31f6: NetNS default: Network connection via eth0 device
wlp0s20f3: NetNS wifins: Network connection via wlan0 device

Access the wifi-Netnamespace with a different local user:
xhost +
sudo ip netns exec wifins su - wifiuser -c urxvt

This command opens a terminal (urxvt), where I can start also graphical applications like Chromium. All commands in this shell are running with a different user (wifiuser) in the Netnamespace. Means wifiuser sees only wlp0s20f3. The default enp0s31f6 is hidden.
This works great with Xorg (using a Shortcut). To handle the switchuser problem in Wayland, someone developed: https://github.com/intgr/ego
That works, if I just want to switch directly to a different user, e.g. ego -u wifiuser chromium-browser, but doesn't work with the root switch in den middle:
xhost +

# urxvt: can't open display :0, aborting
sudo ip netns exec wifins su - wifiuser -c urxvt
ego -u root --sudo ip netns exec wifins su - wifiuser -c urxvt
ego -u root ip netns exec wifins su - wifiuser -c urxvt

# XDG_RUNTIME_DIR unset
ego -u root --sudo /usr/sbin/ip netns exec wifins su -u wifiuser -c urxvt

# User switch works, but Netnamespace is default not wifins
ego -u root --sudo /usr/sbin/ip netns exec wifins bash -c 'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000 WAYLAND_DISPLAY=/run/user/1001/wayland-0 ego -u wifiuser urxvt'
ego -u root /usr/sbin/ip netns exec wifins ego -u wifiuser urxvt

So I'm in the trouble: Either wifiuser doesn't get a displayer or wifiuser doesn't switch to the desired namespace (wifins).
How do I get this problem resolved?
